# Como utilizar valores de cada entry em Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

O código no momento está assim, estou fazendo toda a parte visual no code behind mesmo, sem o implementar nada diretamente no XAML.
Eu crio o numero de entries de acordo com o valor inserido em uma Entry chamada: amostra . Como estou iniciando no Xamarin/C#, não sei como utilizar o valor de cada entry ( gerada dinamicamente) para fazer o calculo, alguém tem alguma ideia do que devo fazer? O codigo está assim:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Leitura : ContentPage
{
    Calculo calculo = new Calculo();

    public Action<object, EventArgs> Clicked { get; }

    public Leitura()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        Entry amostra = new Entry()
        {
            Placeholder = "Quantidade de amostras",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric,
            HeightRequest = 40,
            WidthRequest = 230,
        };

        var layout = new StackLayout();

        Label label = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Amostras",
        };
        layout.Children.Add(label);
        layout.Children.Add(amostra);

        Content = layout;

        amostra.Completed += Amostra_Completed;



        void Amostra_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            amostra.IsEnabled = false;

            calculo.Qnt_amostra = Convert.ToDouble(amostra.Text);
            if (calculo.Qnt_amostra > 100)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Valor Inválido!", "Insira no máximo 100 amostras.", "Ok");
                amostra.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (calculo.Qnt_amostra < 0)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Valor Inválido!", "Valor não pode ser negativo. ", "Ok");
                    amostra.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else
                {


                    for (int i = 0; i < (int)calculo.Qnt_amostra; i++)
                    {   
                       //gostaria de utilizar este valor destas entries,(geradas dinamicamente de acordo com a entrada do usuario),para realizar o calculo
                        var entInput = new Entry();
                        entInput.IsEnabled = true;
                        entInput.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
                        entInput.Placeholder = $"Peso da {(i + 1)}º amostra";

                        entInput.WidthRequest = 200;
                        calculo.Peso = entInput.Text;
                        layout.Children.Add(entInput);
                    }

                    Button botao = new Button
                    {
                        Text = "Calcular",
                        TextColor = Color.White,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
                        WidthRequest = 130,
                        HeightRequest = 40,
                        CornerRadius = 5,

                    };
                    botao.Clicked += Botao;

                    layout.Children.Add(botao);

                    ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView()
                    {
                        Content = layout
                    };
                    Content = scroll;


                }
            }
        }


    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            var acao = await DisplayAlert("Atenção!", "Todos as medidas serão perdidas! Deseja Contiunar?", "Sim", "Cancelar");
            if (acao) await Navigation.PopAsync();
        });
        return true;
    }

    public void Botao(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Resultado(calculo));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir o valor de cada entry, utlizei um novo StackLayout SOMENTE para as entries, então,utilizei o evento OnButtonClicked para um botão qualquer, e ao clicar no botão ele me retorna o desejado.
O processo pode ser feito sem o uso do botao, foi apenas uma preferência própria.

```
//adicionando as entradas
 for (int i = 1; i <= numero_de_entradas_desejadas ; i++)
 // utilizei i=1 pois NÃO se trata de um VETOR, então não há diferença entre iniciar no indice 0, ou não.
        {
            var peso = new Entry();
            peso.Placeholder = $"Peso da {i}° amostra";                
            peso.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            //entradas é o stack layout para as entradas geradas dinamicamente
            entradas.Children.Add(peso);

        }

private async void Botao(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Entry entry in entradas.Children)
        {
            // var variavel_a_ser_manipulada = entry.Text;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Guarde as Entry Dentro de uma Lista
                    List<Entry>  entry = new List<Entry>();
                    entry.Add(new Entry()
                    {
                        Text = "Calcular",
                        TextColor = Color.White,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
                        WidthRequest = 130,
                        HeightRequest = 40,
                        CornerRadius = 5,

                    });
```

.

```
    ObterValores(entry);


    private List<string> ObterValores(List<Entry> entry)
    {
        List<string> ValoresDeCadaEntry = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in entry)
        {
            //Para cada Entry Obtemos o valor do texto
            ValoresDeCadaEntry.Add(item.Text);
            //Adicionamos os valores de Cada Entry a esta Lista
        }
       return ValoresDeCadaEntry;
    }


        string texto;
        foreach (var item in ObterValores(entry))
        {
            texto += item + Environment.NewLine
        }

////Aqui esta o texto
```

Ou pode converter isso para int e fazer calculo com cada elemento de uma lista do tipo int

Comment: entendi, porém como eu faria para exibir esta lista de entries na tela? visto que estou usando um stack layout

Comment: Pode colocar numa string

Comment: @LeonardoOsvalddeSouza que tal assim?

Comment: mas como eu usaria os valores? pois primeiramente o usuário precisa informar-los nas entries